# Use TV remote over HDMI as a control GUI

Tags: hdmi

I want to connect a linux PC with HDMI output to my (Samsung) TV.
This allows to show a screen on the TV.

How can I use the TV's remote as an input device, sent over HDMI to control the PC?

Or in other words, can I make a simple user interface which is shown on the TV and is controlled with the remote control? 
I mainly imagine using the 4 arrow-buttons and the OK to navigate and choose stuff.

Any links to doc or libraries (Java preferred) are welcome.

Comment: It would be lovely. I wish all set top boxes would do this. It's such a pain having to have three remotes for my TV/DVD/Satellite boxes. Unfortunately, given that all the boxes I've ever seen require separate remotes, I suspect there isn't an easy answer for you. If there way, everyone would be doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol used to send the remote control signals is called [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control#CEC). In order to make use of it you will need hardware which supports it, and have drivers for that hardware.

Lacking any more specific information about the hardware you are using, I suggest starting at [this page about CEC support on the Raspberry Pi](http://elinux.org/CEC_%28Consumer_Electronics_Control%29_over_HDMI)